# What are the differences between mind model and other models?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, artificial-intelligence, computation

What are the main differences between mind model and any other models such as conceptual models and ... ?
As far as I know these are some major differences:

1-mind models are dynamic whereas conceptual models are static

2-mind models can implies on many things while not necessity for conceptual

3-and mind models are constructive ? what does this really mean ?

Please give me a comprehensive and vast (as much as possible) view of these subject.

I'm trying to work on mind model which is applicable on machines (computers) by the technologies we have. A practical model not just some thing highly theoretical

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Philosophy SE. Can you please specify what you mean by conceptual models (and models) in general  as well as by models applicable on machines? This would help improve the question. Also, can you please remove all the statements of the type "I'll be so thankful..." and keep the question as objective as possible per SE guidelines.

Comment: @Alexander, I did some of you said, but about the conceptual models I write what I knew about it, conceptual models are well defined models of a object as while also static and you their abstraction level are low

Comment: Do you have a particular definition in mind for "conceptual model" and "mind model"? If so, can you link to where it's coming from?

Comment: @JamesKingsbery no I don't, what I defined is come from some slide lectures which are in Persian

Comment: Do you have a link to that lecture? Or to the work of the lecturer? It's kind of hard to help without some definition of what you mean.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery I think the most appropriate source in English are Aaron Sloman's researches

Comment: Can you give me the words in Persian, and will get you the appropriate English translation?

Comment: @AlexanderSKing I didn't got what you asked exactly ?!!

Comment: "what I defined is come from some slide lectures which are in Persian" -- copy and paste the words in Persian for me, and I will get you the appropriate translation.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing مدل های مفهومی و مدل های ذهنی